# How can I make my GCloud Function open a new SSH connection to consume a SFTP server?

Tags: go, ssh, google-cloud-functions, sftp

My setup requires a Google Function to do some stuff and upload the result to a SFTP server. I'm currently using the basic `sftp` and `crypto/ssh` packages to achieve this. Locally, after some debugging, I was able to retrieve the server's pubkey.

When deploying to GCloud nothing works, of course.

This is what handles the connection on my function

```golang
func Connect(host string, port string, user string, password string) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    hostKey := getHostKey(host)

    var auths []ssh.AuthMethod

    // Use password authentication if provided
    if password != "" {
        auths = append(auths, ssh.Password(password))
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            user,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
        Auth:            auths,
    }

    cipherOrder := config.Ciphers
    config.Ciphers = append(cipherOrder, "aes128-cbc", "3des-cbc")

    sshConn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port, config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return sshConn, nil
}

func getHostKey(host string) ssh.PublicKey {
    file, err := os.Open("/root/.ssh/known_hosts")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to read known_hosts file: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var hostKey ssh.PublicKey
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fields := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
        if len(fields) != 3 {
            continue
        }
        if strings.Contains(fields[0], host) {
            var err error
            hostKey, _, _, _, err = ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(scanner.Bytes())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error parsing %q: %v\n", fields[2], err)
                os.Exit(1)
            }
            break
        }
    }

    if hostKey == nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "No hostkey found for %s", host)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    return hostKey
}
```

The `known_hosts` file doesn't exist. I don't have the pubkey of the server, but with Filezilla I can connect to it just fine.

I had to specify those cyphers because a barebone `ssh hostname` would return `Unable to negotiate...` error

Is there any other way to do this? I'm thinking about uploading my own `known_hosts` file but it doesn't sound like a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was probably over engineering it.

Setting the `ssh.ClientConfig` like this solved the problem:

```golang
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            user,
        Auth:            auths,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
}
```

Anyway I also found a nicer package to easily handle SSH connection, `simplessh`.

```golang
conn, _ := simplessh.ConnectWithPassword(host, user, pass)

client, _ := sftp.NewClient(conn.SSHClient)
```